# abline() function doesn't plot the line in the graph

Tags: r, rstudio, regression, linear-regression

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e14ge.png)abline(lm(Qsales ~ Price)) I am using this function to plot a line where in Qsales is dependent variable and Price is independent variable. 
In R studio,  abline(lm(Qsales ~ Price)) this command runs without error but line is not plotted in the graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In linear model, the response variable comes before your "~" , and this is the yaxis normally. See example:

```
fit = lm(mpg ~ wt,data=mtcars)
with(mtcars,plot(wt,mpg))
abline(fit)
```

So you need to flip it around to abline(lm(Price ~ Qsales)).